# Delete a Question Object from Database after 3 days if it is not answered

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services, backgroundworker

I'm working on a web application project using .net core and I want to self-close(delete) a Question object from the database(MySQL in my case) if it has been posted for 3 days with no answer.
I believe I can use Worker Services but I'm not sure how to use it and if it's logical to have so many background services running in the background (1 service/timer for each question).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just one background service for this job.

I Assume that you already have a service interface:

```
public interface IQuestionService {
    Task<IEnumerable<Question>> GetQuestionsToClose();
    Task CloseQuestions(IEnumerable<Question> questions);
}
```

Than you need to implement your background service:

```
public CloseQuestionsBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IQuestionService questionService;
    public CloseQuestionsBackgroundService(IQuestionService questionService)
    {
        this.questionService = questionService;
    }
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stopToken)
    {
      while (!stopToken.IsCancellationRequested)
      {
          var questionsToClose = questionService.GetQuestionsToClose().ConfigureAwait(false);
          if (questionsToClose.Any())
          {
               await questionService.CloseQuestions(questionsToClose).ConfigureAwait(false);
          }
          await Task.Delay(Timespan.FromSeconds(10)).ConfigureAwait(false); // choose how much time between iterations
      }
   }
}
```

Now you just have to register the background service in the ConfigureService method of your Startup.cs

```
 services.AddHostedService<CloseQuestionsBackgroundService>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just filter them out and don't return them in your queries to the UI.
Delete when you want either manually whenever or have a background job that runs once a day or whenever to delete them

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to create agent job in sql for this with relation between Questions table and answer table and you query is like this

```
Delete from QuestionsTable 
where id not in (select FK_questionID from AnswersTable) 
AND CreateDate < DATE_ADD(NOW() , INTERVAL -3 DAY)
```

and execute this query every day

> also you can update active field in Question Table

I hope it help you

Comment: I did not think that way. It's a great idea, I wonder if it has any drawbacks concerning performance.

Comment: There is no problem with a few million records , also you can optimize query